# pandas: conditions with str.contains()

Tags: python, pandas

I have data

```
url
https://s.youtube.com/api/stats/qoe?fexp=9416891%2C9419451%2C9422596%2C9428269%2C9428398%2C9428492%2C9431012%2C9431657%2C9431674%2C9433096%2C9433380%2C9433946%2C9434803%2C9435467%2C9435526%2C9435876%2C9436275%2C9436302%2C9436484%2C9437553%2C9437967%2C9438327%2C9438699%2C9439362%2C9439652%2C9439816&afs=0.040%3A234%3B%3A%3Ai%2C30.155%3A233%3B%3A234%3Aa%2C60.039%3A234%3B%3A233%3Aa&cos=iOS&c=ios&cl=126064855&ei=7kB1V6PYKYSZWc7Do5AO&snd=0.003%3A0&feature=g-high&cver=11.23.9&conn=0.003%3A3&view=0.040%3A320%3A180%3A2%2C30.155%3A320%3A180%3A2%2C60.039%3A320%3A180%3A2&cmodel=iPhone5%2C1&fmt=229&ad_break_type=0&event=streamingstats&vnd=0.003%3A0&cbrver=11.23.9&vis=0.003%3A0&cosver=9.3.2&vps=0.000%3AN%2C9.468%3AB%2C9.474%3APL%2C15.020%3AB%2C30.180%3APL%2C175.020%3APA%2C238.456%3ASU&cbr=com.google.ios.youtube&bwe=0.040%3A773807&error=20.304%3Aios.cm.-12318%3A5.229%3Aec.cm.-12318%3Bshost.r1---sn-q0c7dn7z.googlevideo.com%2C24.163%3Aios.cm.-12889%3A5.230%3Aec.cm.-12889%3Bshost.r1---sn-q0c7dn7z.googlevideo.com%2C25.655%3Aios.cm.-12889%3A5.230%3Aec.cm.-12889%3Bshost.r1---sn-q0c7dn7z.googlevideo.com&bwm=30.157%3A842717%3A16.579%2C60.044%3A2638763%3A24.468%2C90.043%3A1351020%3A33.381%2C120.042%3A1658050%3A20.401%2C150.042%3A5393743%3A39.706%2C180.040%3A1093239%3A24.764&plid=AAU2gOYQwAPoGwuT&cnetwork=wifi&cplatform=mobile&vfs=0.040%3A230%3B%3A230%3A%3Ai%2C30.155%3A269%3B%3A230%3A230%3Aa%2C60.039%3A229%3B%3A230%3A269%3Aa&ns=yt&docid=QxsmWxxouIM&bat=0.006%3A0.61%3A0%2C157.152%3A0.60%3A0&bh=9.468%3A4.8%2C9.474%3A4.8%2C15.020%3A0.0%2C30.155%3A5.3%2C30.180%3A10.6%2C60.039%3A44.9&cpn=gl2S0rZF013jWHTp
https://s.youtube.com/api/stats/qoe?cmodel=iPhone5%2C1&c=ios&ns=yt&bat=265.123%3A0.59%3A0&plid=AAU2gOYQwAPoGwuT&cplatform=mobile&cbrver=11.23.9&event=streamingstats&cos=iOS&fmt=229&vps=267.521%3ASU&cl=126064855&fexp=9416891%2C9419451%2C9422596%2C9428269%2C9428398%2C9428492%2C9431012%2C9431657%2C9431674%2C9433096%2C9433380%2C9433946%2C9434803%2C9435467%2C9435526%2C9435876%2C9436275%2C9436302%2C9436484%2C9437553%2C9437967%2C9438327%2C9438699%2C9439362%2C9439652%2C9439816&cnetwork=wifi&ad_break_type=0&cpn=gl2S0rZF013jWHTp&cosver=9.3.2&docid=QxsmWxxouIM&feature=g-high&cbr=com.google.ios.youtube&bwm=267.526%3A266451%3A2.419&ei=7kB1V6PYKYSZWc7Do5AO&cplayer=NATIVE_MEDIA_PLAYER&cver=11.23.9
http://gsp1.apple.com/pep/gcc
```

And I need to get all string, that contain `youtube`. I try

```
df[df['url'].str.contains("youtube")]
```

But it doesn't return correct dataframe, it doesn't delete others.
head of df:

```
size                                                url  
5663    316       http://captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html  
5670    606  http://counter.yadro.ru/hit?uhttp://m.vk.com/;...  
24453   316       http://captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html  
26818   569  https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conver...  
26821   597  https://s.youtube.com/api/stats/watchtime?fexp...  
26822   597  https://s.youtube.com/api/stats/qoe?fexp=94168...
```

dtype

```
date       datetime64[ns]
id                  int64
request            object
browser            object
version             int64
type               object
size                int64
url                object
dtype: object
```

Comment: type `df.head()` and `df.dtypes`

Comment: @Noobie add to question

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: last chance, see now

Answer (score 0):

try

```
df[df['myurl']=df.url.to_string()
df[df['myurl'].str.contains('youtube', case=False)]
```

Comment: it also returns all url

Comment: @IanS add to question

Comment: it printed others values

Comment: after first string return `KeyError: "['http://captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html'\n 'http://counter.yadro.ru/hit?uhttp://m.vk.com/;917762365'\n 'http://captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html'\n 'https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1001680686/?appversion=11.23.9&bundleid=com.google.ios.youtube&data.screen_name=iOS_YT_App_Open_V2300&lat=0&osversion=9.3.2&rdid=7CA41879-DAD8-408D-B984-DEECC974B426&remarketing_only=1&sdkversion=ct-sdk-i-v3.3.1&timestamp=1467304723.088273&usage_tracking_enabled=0'\n
`